# how to set RAILS_ENV to staging when deployed by "$ cap staging deploy"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

Capistrano 3.1 is used to deploy rails app 4.1.0

I specify different databases for production and staging in my **database.yml**

After I deployed with "**$ cap staging deploy**", everything is fine, except that the production database is used, instead of the staging database.

I guess ***RAILS_ENV*** on the server has NOT been set correctly, how can I do that? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: are you using unicorn or something to spawn rails? drop the configuration there!

Comment: if that is the case, see my post below, but also make sure you have `set(:unicorn_env) { rails_env }` in your condig/deploy.rb

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have installed the [Capistrano Rails](https://github.com/capistrano/rails) Gem and it is performing the rake db:migrate for you.

The default behaviour is to use the stage name for RAILS_ENV, eg: RAILS_ENV="staging".

If you need it to be something else, in your deploy/staging.rb, you can use:

set :rails_env, 'testing'

Comment: yeah, I installed Capistrano Rails.

Comment: I once tried adding 
set :rails_env, "staging"
but no luck.
I was told this sentence will once take effect during  "rake db:migrate", so it won't help to setup the app RAILS_ENV.

Comment: What are you using to run your rails app?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the staging server, and set unicorn start flag from "-E production" to "-E staging".
Fix this issue.